# Simplified Device Connection and Message Publishing to AWS IoT Core Without Certificates

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I am working on a project that involves connecting devices to AWS IoT Core and publishing messages without the complexity of dealing with certificates and other intricate details. The goal is to simplify the process and make it more straightforward for devices to communicate with AWS IoT Core.

I have explored the official documentation, but it seems to emphasize the use of certificates for secure connections. While security is crucial, for the scope of my project, I am looking for a more straightforward approach that avoids the hassle of generating and managing certificates.

Is there a simplified method or best practice that allows devices to connect and publish messages to AWS IoT Core without the need for extensive certificate handling? I want to strike a balance between security and simplicity for my specific use case.

Any insights, code snippets, or recommended libraries that provide a streamlined solution would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use custom authorizer which is meant to be used for legacy devices that cannot use x509 certificate.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/custom-auth-tutorial.html